# Problem with device storage, incompleted files take up space

Tags: storage

I am using Lebovo S860. I have quite a big problem with my device storage. Sometimes I try to move a large file to the device (it has 16 GB built-in memory, no slot) and it fails, but the storage is now taken as if I have 80% of the file on my phone. But since the file is not full - problably temorary somewhere, I can not find and delete it, leaving me with no file and no storage.

Example - I have 3.2 GB free and I try to move a 1.8 GB file to my phone - works well until 90%. Then it says not enough storage and fails, which leaves me with 1.6 GB free memory and no files transferred.

Does anyone know why is this and how to find and delete the temporary files?

Answer (score 0):

Open up settings in your device and go to storage option. Select miscellaneous files and you'll see temporary files sorted by size.
Or install fx file explorer application and set your device storage files sorted by date. Or size! Then you'll see which files have taken your storage.

Comment: I tried, but Misc can not be clicked on my phone. Apps and Media open other menus but not the Misc category. Do you know any apps that can do what you said instead of the built-in explorer?